# AttributeError in Multi_plane_detection code

Tags: python, plane, open3d

I bumped into this code
https://github.com/yuecideng/Multiple_Planes_Detection

```
def RemoveNoiseStatistical(pc, nb_neighbors=20, std_ratio=2.0):
pcd = NumpyToPCD(pc)
cl, ind = pcd.remove_statistical_outlier(nb_neighbors=nb_neighbors, std_ratio=std_ratio)
return PCDToNumpy(cl)


points = RemoveNoiseStatistical(points, nb_neighbors=50, std_ratio=0.5)
```

[when I debug this code, the error message appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpNrS.png)

Comment: Did you install the correct version of open3d using the `requirements.txt' file with pip?

Comment: ㄴ Thank you for your comment. The problem happened because of the version of python. I took care of only version of open3D. :(